# when should I used Lambda or Anonymous method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand the working of block , proc and lambda experession but what i dont understand that when to use anonymous method in code.

What is the problem which Anonymous solves ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons I use lambdas in this way in Ruby is when I need a closure to capture stuff from the surrounding scope, which for example in smaller scripts I sometimes find more convenient than passing things around as arguments. Other people (ab)use top-level instance variables for that, but I don't like that much.

Update as requested: Here's a little example:

```
shift_timestamp = -> ts do
  t = Time.parse(ts.gsub(',','.')) + options[:time]
  "#{t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")},#{t.usec.to_s[0..2]}"
end
```

This is for a little tool I wrote for shifting subtitles. It's a short script and writing it this way allowed me to close over `options` and access it inside the lambda without having to pass it in. As I said, nothing funky, but for small scripts I sometimes like to do this (where "this" is parsing options, writing 1 or 2 lambdas that use those options, use the lambdas instead of methods later on).

Comment: Can you give a short example of where this would be useful? Just interested …

Answer (score 2):

One very common usage of lambdas is for lazy-loading of (and passing parameters to) ActiveRecord relations in scopes:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, lambda { |today| where('published_at >= ?', today) }
end
```

(from [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html))

In general though, these closure methods are a concise way of operating on (e.g.) a collection of data all at once, or storing code as data to be passed around to other functions.

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so that might not be the best example.